# C# MVC 4/5 - Where is the Id stored?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I need help to understand this thing.

Lets say i have an Action like this

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
      var model = new Model();
      return View(model);
    }
```

And an Action like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Model model, int id)
    {

    }
```

The question:

When i do a GET request (e.g. http://url.com/controller/Edit/2)

Then the id of the action method will have value 2, and we will see the edit View.

Now when i change the Id in the URL (e.g. http://url.com/controller/Edit/4)
And make a submit(POST) to the other ActionMethod, the id will still have the value 2. (and not 4! which i expected to be)

Why is this? can someone explain this to me?

Thanks!

Comment: in model, do you have id field? if yes, you need to set its value as well

Comment: Please show your view. In `POST` request, the action paremeters are bound from `FORM` values. Probably some form input (which has `id` name) value is 2 - it was probably set in `GET` action.

Comment: Its probably inside a hidden input within the form - its hidden as you dont want people changing the ID (keys) when editing a model. You could use EditorFor(m=>m.id) if you wanted to expose it. In your GET above though, you are just returning a generic view though aren't you, rather than something specific to the passed in ID?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC uses value providers in following order:

1. Previously bound action parameters, when the action is a child action
2. Form fields
3. The property values in the JSON Request body (for AJAX requests)
4. Route data
5. Querystring parameters
6. Posted files

So, when model binder tries to find value for parameter `id` it first looks for form data in the request. Thus you are passing `Model` which has property with name `id` form data will look like:

```
id=2&name=foo
```

So it successfully finds match for parameter named `id` in form data and does not go further to analyze route data or query string.

If you will modify form data which are passed in your request and remove `id=2` part, then id parameter from query string will be used both for model and id parameters of action.

You cannot use automatic binding here, but you always can get query string parameter manually (though I find this approach very confusing - better approach will be using different name for `id` parameter):

```
string id = Request.QueryString.Get("id");
```

Suggested reading: [The Features and Foibles of ASP.NET MVC Model Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx)